# Unable to draw SVG coordinates accurately with Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, svg, image-processing, colors

I've been struggling for days with drawing an SVG vectorscope using JavaScript. The purpose of the project is to analyze an image, plot every pixel on the scope, and draw the trace between the rendered pixels. However, I'm not able to accurately plot the reference color targets on the SVG, so something is wrong in either my code or my understanding.

**UPDATE:**

After looking through the docs for Kdenlive, I was able to get closer by using their RGB to YUV transformation matrices.

However, I'm still not getting exactly what DaVinci Resolve is showing in the reference image. This is regardless of using either the RGB to YUV or RGB to YPbPr transformations.

I've updated the link to my CodePen, my code, and relevant details below.

Here is a link to my [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/redwhiteblack0/pen/mdowOMa?editors=1010). And here is my code copied here:

```js
// Constants - from KdenLive
const YUV_R = [-.147, .615];
const YUV_G = [-.289, -.515];
const YUV_B = [.437, -.100];
const YUV_Cy = [.147, -.615];
const YUV_Mg = [.289, .515];
const YUV_Yl = [-.437, .100];

const YPbPr_R = [-.169, .5];
const YPbPr_G = [-.331, -.419];
const YPbPr_B = [.5, -.081];
const YPbPr_Cy = [.169, -.5];
const YPbPr_Mg = [.331, .419];
const YPbPr_Yl = [-.5, .081];


// RGB to YUV matrix - from KdenLive
const mRgbToYuv = [
  [0.29900, 0.58700, 0.11400],
  [-0.14741, -0.28939, 0.43680],
  [0.61478, -0.51480, -0.09998]
]

// RGB to YPbPr matrix - from KdenLive
const mRgbToYPbPr = [
  [0.299000, 0.587000, 0.114000],
  [-0.168736, -0.331264, 0.500000],
  [0.500000, -0.418688, -0.081312]
]

// From KdenLive docs:
// Note that YUV and YPbPr are not the same.
// * YUV is used for analog transfer of PAL/NTSC
// * YPbPr is used for analog transfer of YCbCr sources
// like DVD/DVB.
// It does _not_ matter for the Vectorscope what color space
// the input video is; The used color space is just a tool
// to visualize the hue. The difference is merely that the
// scope looks slightly different when choosing the respectively
// other color space; The way the Vectorscope works stays the same.

// YCbCr is basically YPbPr for digital use (it is defined
// on a range of {16,219} for Y and {16,240} for Cb/Cr components).

// See also:
// http://www.poynton.com/ColorFAQ.html
// https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vektorskop
// https://www.elektroniktutor.de/geraetetechnik/vektskop.html


// Util functions
const degToRad = (deg) => {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
};

const rgbToYuv = (rgb_vec) => {
  const r = rgb_vec[0] / 255;
  const g = rgb_vec[1] / 255;
  const b = rgb_vec[2] / 255;
  
  return {
    y: (0.299000 * r) + (0.587000 * g) + (0.114000 * b),
    u: (-0.14741 * r) + (-0.28939 * g) + (0.43680 * b),
    v: (0.61478 * r) + (-0.51480 * g) + (-0.09998 * b)
  }
}

const rgbToYPbPr = (rgb_vec) => {
  const r = rgb_vec[0] / 255;
  const g = rgb_vec[1] / 255;
  const b = rgb_vec[2] / 255;
  
  return {
    y: (0.299000 * r) + (0.587000 * g) + (0.114000 * b),
    u: (-0.168736 * r) + (-0.28939 * g) + ( 0.500000 * b),
    v: (0.500000 * r) + (-0.418688 * g) + (-0.081312 * b)
  }
}

const yuvToCartesianSvgCoords = ({u, v}, c_off) => {
  return {
    x: c_off + c_off * u,
    y: c_off - c_off * v
  }
}

const plotRefTarget = (col_yuv, fill) => {
  const targetPoint = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
  targetPoint.setAttribute("r", 4);
  targetPoint.setAttribute("cx", yuvToCartesianSvgCoords(col_yuv, 256).x);
  targetPoint.setAttribute("cy", yuvToCartesianSvgCoords(col_yuv, 256).y);
  targetPoint.setAttribute("fill", fill)
  document.getElementById("refTargetAreas").appendChild(targetPoint);
}


// Draw skin tone line along -I axis
const I_LINE_ROT = degToRad(33);

// Rotate line to correct quadrant
const getCartesianSVGCoords = (r, phi, c_off) => {
  return {
    x: (c_off * r * Math.cos(phi + 1.5 * Math.PI)) + c_off,
    y: (c_off * r * Math.sin(phi + 1.5 * Math.PI)) + c_off
  };
};

const skin_tone_line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
skin_tone_line.setAttribute("x1", 256);
skin_tone_line.setAttribute("y1", 256);
skin_tone_line.setAttribute("x2", getCartesianSVGCoords(1, -1 * I_LINE_ROT, 256).x);
skin_tone_line.setAttribute("y2", getCartesianSVGCoords(1, -1 * I_LINE_ROT, 256).y);
document.getElementById("skinToneLine").appendChild(skin_tone_line);


// Plot Reference Points
// Red YUV
const red_yuv = rgbToYuv([255, 0, 0])
// console.log("Red YUV: ", red_yuv);

plotRefTarget(red_yuv, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");


// Magenta
const mg_yuv = rgbToYuv([255, 0, 255])
// console.log("Magenta YUV: ", mg_yuv);

plotRefTarget(mg_yuv, "rgb(255, 0, 255)");


// Blue
const blue_yuv = rgbToYuv([0, 0, 255])
// console.log("Blue YUV: ", mg_yuv);

plotRefTarget(blue_yuv, "rgb(0, 0, 255)");


// Cyan
const cy_yuv = rgbToYuv([0, 255, 255])
// console.log("Blue YUV: ", cy_yuv);

plotRefTarget(cy_yuv, "rgb(0, 255, 255)");


// Green
const green_yuv = rgbToYuv([0, 255, 0])
// console.log("Green YUV: ", green_yuv);

plotRefTarget(green_yuv, "rgb(0, 255, 0)");


// Yellow
const yel_yuv = rgbToYuv([255, 255, 0])
// console.log("Yellow YUV: ", yel_yuv);

plotRefTarget(yel_yuv, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");



// Draw tick marks every 5 degrees
const drawTick = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
  const line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
  line.setAttribute("x1", x1);
  line.setAttribute("y1", y1);
  line.setAttribute("x2", x2);
  line.setAttribute("y2", y2);
  document.getElementById("tickMarks").appendChild(line);
};

for (let phi = 0; phi < 360; phi += 5) {
  const angle_rad = degToRad(phi);
  const x1 = 256 + 256 * Math.cos(angle_rad);
  const y1 = 256 + 256 * Math.sin(angle_rad);
  const x2 = 256 + (phi % 10 === 0 ? 240 : 248) * Math.cos(angle_rad);
  const y2 = 256 + (phi % 10 === 0 ? 240 : 248) * Math.sin(angle_rad);

  drawTick(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}


// Handle img button toggle
const imgButtonToggleEl = document.getElementById("imgToggleBtn");

const imgRefEl = document.getElementById("scope-img-ref");
imgRefEl.style.display = "none";

imgButtonToggleEl.onclick = () => {
  if(imgRefEl.style.display === "none") {
      imgRefEl.style.display = "block" 
  } else {
       imgRefEl.style.display = "none" 
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  position: relative;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#scope-img-ref {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#scope-svg {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  z-index: 10;
}

#scope-svg svg {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
}

.view {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="view" id="scope-img-ref">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FYyYT0q/vectorscope-ref.png" alt="vectorscope-ref" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="view" id="scope-svg">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />

      <!-- Axes -->
      <line x1="0" y1="256" x2="512" y2="256" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
      <line x1="256" y1="0" x2="256" y2="512" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

      <!-- Skin tone line -->
      <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" id="skinToneLine">
      </g>

      <!-- Reference target areas -->
      <g id="refTargetAreas">
      </g>

      <!-- Draw tick marks -->
      <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" id="tickMarks">
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Toggle button for image underlay -->
<div>
  <button id="imgToggleBtn">Toggle Ref Image</button>
</div>
```

I've placed a button that toggles on a reference image. This is a screenshot I took from DaVinci Resolve Studio showing their vectorscope. My timeline settings are: **Timeline Color space: Rec.709 (Scene)**, and **Output Color Space: Rec.709 (Scene)**. I haven't added any color space transforms or other nodes in between.

The DaVinci Resolve image shows the trace from a JPEG image of the SMPTE color bars. The reference points are mapped are accuratley - as one would expect.

I was able to accurately match the Red and Cyan reference points using the transformation matrices provided by Kdenlive.

My skin tone line also lies on the same -I axis as in DaVinci Resolve, so I know that at least part of my logic is correct here.

However, the Magenta, Blue, Green, and Yellow reference points are still off - and I don't know why. At the very least, the Magenta and Green points are co-linear, as well as Blue and Yellow, so I can see I'm on the right track - I'm just missing the last step here.

I know that Kdenlive does some more scaling for their vectorscope, but I should be already scaling things to fit my SVG, right?

Here is the particular file I was using as a reference from their Github: https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive/blob/27b2e929ec77a885bf580526d6a8453d881b64e8/src/scopes/colorscopes/vectorscopegenerator.cpp#L102

So what am I still missing here?

I know I still have a lot to learn in this area, so any help and resources for further research are much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Web colors are usually in the sRGB [color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_spaces). What colorspace does Resolve use? Your `rgbToYCbCr` function has a reference to ITU-R BT.709, which is the HDTV colorspace (same primaries, but different gamma values than sRGB).

Comment: @ccprog Thanks for the response! I have the SMPTE color bars reference image in my timeline with both the Timeline color space and Output color space set to Rec.709. I haven't added any color space transform nodes. I see how the ITU-R BT.709 gamma would be throwing me off - but I still don't see how the HSV values are being mapped. Do I have to apply a gamma correction before converting to HSV in order for the reference targets to match?

Comment: You just removed more or less the complete code example. Please, while editing, use the "<>" button from the editor's icon bar or press Ctrl+M, and then copy your code from CodePen to the equivalent fields shown.

Comment: @ccprog Yes, I was having trouble with the formatter. It's added now. Thanks!

Comment: The coefficients you use are, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) the BT.601 values, not BT.709 as you assume. Does it help to change them?

Comment: @ccprog Yes it does! Ok, this is starting to come together. I've updated the Codepen to use the weights from the BT.709 matrix now and they're almost there. If you can see - does it appear that I just have a scaling issue remaining now?

Comment: @ccprog Amazing help! I was able to match the Resolve reference points by using the BT.709 weights and by multiplying the Cb and Cr values by a scaling factor of around 1.23. Here is my updated Codepen with the correct reference points: [https://codepen.io/redwhiteblack0/pen/MWxobxo?editors=0010](https://codepen.io/redwhiteblack0/pen/MWxobxo?editors=0010). So this is great! The last remaining question I have is why does the scaling factor works here? Is it related to gamma? Is it due to a 75% saturation target? I want to make this precise, and not just have an arbitrary number in my code

Comment: I came up with `1.25*c_off` in `yuvToCartesianSvgCoords`, but why? First, note that u and v (or Cb and Cr) are in the intervall [-0.5..0.5], so it should be `2*c_off`. For 75% I would have expected a factor of 2*0.75 = 1.5.

Comment: @ccprog Amazing. Thank you so much. If you want to add a solution, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Really appreciate all your help